# Parametized Constructor Not an Copy one

Tags: c++, constructor

Say we have a class A that contains as a member of the same class:

```
Class A{
   const A &a;
}
```

I want to create a parametized constructor that passed the value of that member, but I do not want to define the copy constructor of the class.

```
A(const A& memberA): a(memberA)     {}
```

How could indicate the compiler such thing?

Thanks

Comment: Show us how you want to use `A`. In particular, how the first instance is created.

Comment: Wouldn't you get an infinite recursion problem here? I cannot see how you could instantiate an `A`, unless it refers to itself.

Comment: @juanchopanza though `A a(a);` seems like it would be entertaining as a joke someday, somewhere...

Comment: "Show us how you want to use A. In particular, how the first instance is created" That made me think. Is it possible? lol I will use pointers :) There should be one instance that will have no member. You are right @juanchopanza

Comment: Apart from the boot strapping being the first problem. You seem to be asking for two copy constructors probably behaving differently. Anyway the just for the sake of completion I would like to mention the most wrong way to solve the boot strapping which would be to do A first(*((A*)0));

Comment: I meant `A first(*((A*)0));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A constructor that can take just a reference to the class it constructs *is* a copy constructor, whether you want it to be one or not. Copy constructors are defined thus:

> A non-template constructor for `class X` is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments.

You could declare it `explicit` to restrict how the class can be copied (preventing `A a = A()` for example), but it's still a copy constructor as long as it has that signature.

Answer (score 4):

You can define this constructor as `explicit`.

(That's a good rule for all constructors that can be called with one parameter.)

Comment: How `explict` make a difference? It just prevents `=` sign.

Comment: @iammilind: normally, a constructor like Mario's would automatically become the copy constructor of the class and thus be called implicitly in situations like e.g. pass-by-value Making it `explicit` means you need to call it explicitly to invoke it, it will not be invoked implicitly by the compiler.