# Why is the argument to a copy ctor passed by reference?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, copy-constructor

Why isn't the argument passed by value ?

When I tried it, my compiler just gave me a message saying "you probably meant `Foo(const Foo&)` ."

What is the reason for this ?

Comment: Actually because if you pass by value compiler have to make a copy of ypuir varibale, so call copy constructor. In result you'll have to make a copy to make a copy, but you need to make a copy to make a copy and so on.

Comment: We have a similar SO question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413419/parametized-constructor-not-an-copy-one

Comment: @40two Mainly to avoid infinite recursion

Answer (score 7):

Because pass by value requires a copy constructor in the first place.

So to avoid infinite recursion, the pass by reference copy constructor has to be defined before the pass by value version if we really want to have a pass by value one. As it does not make much sense to have a pass by value copy constructor, the standard forbids it.

Comment: so.. wouldn't that require a value(again) ?

Comment: @prodicus Indeed. So to avoid this, one needs to define other version first.

Comment: You can't have a "pass by value version" at all.

Comment: @T.C. That's true, and it wouldn't make much sense to have one either. But OP asks for the reason, so here it is.

Comment: Well, this explanation makes sense at the lowest technical level. But the C++ language is flush with automatic rewrites of code. Formal arguments of function type are adjusted to pointers, formal arguments of array type are adjusted to pointers, actual arguments to variadic functions are promoted, and possibly more. So it's also necessary to address this aspect, why there isn't an automatic rewrite. Possible reasons include that it would not save much typing, that it would complicate the language and increase the size of the standard, and also that nobody's expressed any interest... :)

Answer (score 5):

You are simply not allowed to pass it by value - §12.8 [class.copy]/p6 of the standard explicitly prohibits it :

> A declaration of a constructor for a class `X` is ill-formed if its
>   first parameter is of type (optionally cv-qualified) `X` and either
>   there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have
>   default arguments. A member function template is never instantiated to
>   produce such a constructor signature.

The reason for this prohibition, as explained in the comments, is infinite recursion - "to make a copy, you have to make a copy" doesn't make much sense.